# Angularjs : Controller values not getting displayed in html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've just started learning angular.js . I wrote a  basic controller in app.js file and set its property. I'm trying to access this data inside html page but in vain. Controller property values are not getting shown in webpage. Below is the code :

app.js :

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('gemStore',[]);
    var gem = {name: 'Diamond', price: 120, description: 'Hard'};
    app.controller('StoreController', function() {
        this.product = gem;

    });



})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/app.js" ></script>

<p> {{"Hello, Angular!"}}</p>

<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
<h2>{{store.product.price}}</h2>
<h3>{{store.product.description}}</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me where am i going wrong!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "controller as"-syntax was added in 1.2.0 (or thereabouts), I don't think it was in 1.0.7. Try using a newer version of Angular. If you're stuck with 1.0.7 then you need to use `$scope`.

Answer (score 2):

Your AngularJS version doesn't supports `StoreController as store` syntax. Change it to `StoreController` and simply remove the `store`s. Also you must [`inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) the [`scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) object into the controller and set its properties instead.

Here is the updated and working code.

```js
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
var gem = {
  name: 'Diamond',
  price: 120,
  description: 'Hard'
};

app.controller('StoreController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.product = gem;
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

  <p>{{"Hello, Angular!"}}</p>

  <div ng-controller="StoreController">
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{product.price}}</h2>
    <h3>{{product.description}}</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller as syntax in angular was introduced in version 1.2 and you are using version 1.0.7. If you update the version of angular in your script tags to 1.2 or above it will work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

You can also see this working fine on the following link: http://jsbin.com/tadinesime/2/edit

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
ng-app="gemStore"
```

on the body (or in whatever html tag which contains your angularjs code)

here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/49yrj986/

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the incorrect angular js version. I upgraded it to 1.3.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this is a course on http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/1/section/2/our-first-controller  if someone else wants to try these tutorials